# How i return a List<UserRoles> of a controller from my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a vision with the code below, my idea is to return a list of HttpPost UserRoles. My UserRole model is as follows:

```
idUser
idRole
```

How can I do?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserRole</legend>

       @Html.Label("Select User:") @Html.DropDownList("UserList", String.Empty)
        @{            
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
            {
               <div id="@item.NameLower">
                   <b>@item.Name</b>
                   <input type="checkbox" value="@item.NameLower" />
               </div>

            }
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "Index")
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Roles = db.roles.ToList();
        ViewData["UserList"] = new SelectList(db.users, "Id", "Nome");

        return View();
    }
```

And my database:
 [image: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/3227/userrole.jpg]

I create de ViewModel, like:

```
namespace Sacer.ViewModels
{
    public class UserRoleModel
    {
        public List<User> usuario
        {
            get
            {
                return db.users.ToList();
            }
        }

        private SacerContext db = new SacerContext();
        public List<Role> role
        {
            get
            {
                return db.roles.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

and my controller
`

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["ListaUsuarios"] = new SelectList(db.users, "Id", "Nome");        
            var model = new UserRoleModel();
            return View(model);
        }
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserRole</legend>

        @Html.Label("Selecione o Usuário:") @Html.DropDownList("ListaUsuarios", String.Empty)
        @{
                foreach (Sacer.Models.Role role in Model.role)
                {
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@role.NomeMinusculo" name="Roles" /> @role.Nome
                    </div>
                }                  
         }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Criar" onclick="GerarLista" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar à lista", "Index")
</div>
```

but, how i insert in table userRoles?

Comment: Unanswerable without knowing what's in the ViewBag.

Comment: And consider replacing the ViewBag with a properViewModel.

Comment: In ViewBag exists all kind of Roles from my database. Roles contain name and ID. If in UserRole table  exist the user id, and role id, he have permission to acess the view. If not have, display the error page.

Comment: Why is a list of roles labeled with "Select User:" ?

Comment: At least your question is clearer now: how to present and retrieve a CheckedList of Items.

Comment: Sorry, i am new in all of this... really sorry. The list is to indicate to users who will set the rules. The SelectList has registered users, after choosing one, will checked options it will have.

Comment: Read up on using (View)Models, this requires one.